# Ideal which becomes a principal ideal in a higher field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I am working on the question of why the ideal $(2,\sqrt{-6})$ is not a  principal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$, but becomes one in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{2})$.

To prove that it is not principal in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$, I first computed the norm of this ideal:
$$N((2,\sqrt{-6}))=|\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]/(2,\sqrt{-6})|=|\mathbb{Z}[T]/(2,T,T^2+6)|=|\mathbb{F}_2|=2.$$
Then I supposed that there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$, $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{-6}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, so that $(2,\sqrt{-6})=(\alpha)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$. Without loss of generality I assumed that $a$ and $b$ already are in $\mathbb{Z}$ (if not, multiply by a suitable unit). Then the norm of the ideal is
$$N((\alpha))=N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=(a+b\sqrt{-6})(a-b\sqrt{-6})=a^2+6b^2.$$ But the equation $a^2+6b^2=2$ can't be solved in $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $(2,\sqrt{-6})$ is not a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$.

Now the next step is to find $\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{2})$, so that $(2,\sqrt{-6})=(\beta)$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{2})$. How can I find this $\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done the hard part!

First note that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt2)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt2)$. Observe that $\sqrt{2}$ divides both $2$ and $\sqrt{-6}$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt2)$, since
$$2=\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt 2\\\sqrt{-6}=\sqrt2\sqrt{-3}.$$

Hence $(\sqrt{-6},2)\subset(\sqrt2)$.

Moreover, $$\sqrt{-6}\cdot\sqrt{-3}=\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt2\text{ and}\\\sqrt 2 = 3\sqrt2-2\sqrt2,$$
so $$\sqrt2 = (\sqrt{-6}\cdot\sqrt{-3})-(2\cdot\sqrt2)\in(\sqrt{-6},2).$$
Hence $(\sqrt{-6},2)\supset(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Since we have to proof these inclusions in the accompanying ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{2})$, I have the following problem: for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ I know that the ring of integers is given by $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{d})$ if $d\equiv 2,3 \mod 4$ and by $\mathbb{Z}(\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2})$ if $d\equiv 1 \mod 4$. So how does the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{2})$ look like (maybe it is $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{2})$)? Why is it allowed to divide by $\sqrt{2}$? I don't see why it is an unit in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{2})$.@Mathmo123

Comment: We can't divide by $\sqrt2$ in general. However, $\sqrt{-3}$ is an algebraic integer. By writing $\frac{\sqrt{-6}}{\sqrt2}$ I was trying to illustrate that $\sqrt{-3}$ is an element of the field, although this may have confused matters. I've edited the question to clarify. I think the ring of integers should be $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{2}]$, although knowing this is not necessary for this question.